# Apply local setting to .vimrc

Tags: vimrc

Is it possible to overwrite a `.vimrc` setting with a local one?

For example:

I have `set background=light` in my .vimrc file

And then, while editing another file I decide to change that setting, so I run the command `:set background=dark` in order to apply it to the current session.

Let's say I want to keep this setting. I should open my .vimrc file and make the change. And here is my question: can I make this change without visiting the .vimrc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in that is specifically designed for that.

You can certainly do something like `:!echo 'set background=dark' >> ~/.vimrc` but I can only imagine the mess that would result from doing that a few times. Same for the built-in `:help :mkvimrc`, which is not granular at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could always add a plugin to your runtime:

```
~/.vim/plugin/local_vimrc.vim
```

Another option would be to simply source a file in your vimrc file:

```
if filereadable(expand('~/.vimrc.local'))
  source ~/.vimrc.local
endif
```

Comment: That alone would not solve the question, would it? You would need to somehow (automatically?) write to the local vimrc. Editing an extra file is just as good as editing `.vimrc` directly unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I think that depends on the needs. If your main `vimrc` is under version control, but you need a few settings on a specific machine then this method would allow you to keep your `vimrc` in sync and "override" a few settings. Unless I am missing the point, which is possible

Comment: I see what you mean and that's one way to read the question. I understood the OP was looking for a way to persistently `:set foo`. I guess (at least) one of us is mistaken and only the OP could tell who it is. Thank you for clarifying.